# SSRS Client Certificate Custom Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, reporting-services, client-certificates

I'm running into an issue when trying to implement custom authentication for SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) using client certificates, with the sample forms authentication setup from https://github.com/Microsoft/Reporting-Services/tree/master/CustomSecuritySample as a base. Specifically, I am trying to access the `CERT_SUBJECT` server variable in `logon.aspx`, but I have tried multiple methods to access it and they all return an empty value:

- `Request.ClientCertificate.Subject`
- `Context.Request.ServerVariables["CERT_SUBJECT"]`
- `Request.ServerVariables["CERT_SUBJECT"]`

I have an IIS server that requires client certificates which redirects the `/reports` and `/reportserver` paths to the proper SSRS URL (`localhost/reports` and `localhost/reportserver`) using URL rewrite. I have also configured the rewrite rules to passthrough `CERT_SUBJECT`, and I can confirm that the server variable being is passed through correctly by forcing the rule to redirect to the raw variable `{C:0}`, which does indeed display the cert subject in the address bar.

**reports/web.config:**

```xml
<rules>
    <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:8080/reports/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" />
        <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
            <add input="{CERT_SUBJECT}" pattern="(.*)" />
        </conditions>
        <serverVariables>
            <set name="CERT_SUBJECT" value="{C:0}" />
        </serverVariables>
    </rule>
</rules>
```

**reportserver/web.config:**

```xml
<rules>
    <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:8080/reportserver/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" logRewrittenUrl="false" />
        <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
            <add input="{CERT_SUBJECT}" pattern="(.*)" />
        </conditions>
        <serverVariables>
            <set name="CERT_SUBJECT" value="{C:0}" />
        </serverVariables>
    </rule>
</rules>
```

So I have limited the problem to something related to SSRS's configuration files or an ASP.net setting I am unaware of. However, I am extremely inexperienced with web servers and ASP.net, so I have no idea where to look next.

I have basic forms authentication (username/password) working fine by following the sample.

This is similar to the issue found here: https://forums.asp.net/post/6239941.aspx